# React native Project is giving an error of React-rncore in xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

[link here to see Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeXzO.jpg)

I can't run the React native app it gives this error so how to fix it?
I am using **Intel chip**. Please anyone can provide an answer

I tried many ways. like re-installing cocoa pod in brew and updated node to 20.10.

and I reinstalled Ruby

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurred on my MacBook with the M2 chip some time ago.

Here is how I solved it:

This issue happens when the parent folder names contain white spaces. Removing these white spaces in folder names resolved the problem.